# Shub command not found

Tags: macos, scrapy

I am trying to use the shub commands in order to use scrapinghub.

I installed shub using

```
python3 -m pip install shub
```

I can find the shub folder in usr/local/bin yet when I run any shub commands I get

```
sudo: shub: command not found
```

Comment: Why do you run it with `sudo`? Is `/use/local/bin` in your PATH?

Comment: @Gallaecio Yeh it is, when I run it without sudo I get a zsh: command not found error

Comment: If you can use `sudo`, you should be able to do `sudo pip3 install shub` to install `shub` system-wide, and from then on be able to use `shub` without `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

download package from [shub](https://pypi.org/project/shub/),

1)unzip it if it is zipped

2)cd into the directory containing setup.py

3)python setup.py install (or use python3 setup.py)

Answer (score 0):

My trick (I had the issue on windows) was to try "python -m shub"
I noticed the shub code was installed under python-> site packages, not in my conda environment site packages. Output of pip install shub reveals where it thinks shub lives.